# GPU fan speeds up extremely, if the laptop has been idle for a while

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, intel-graphics, fan

So, this seems a bit strange but if I leave the laptop and go for a snack or cup of tea, and I return 15-20 minutes laters, I will hear a exceptionally high voice from my laptop, as if all fans are working at maximum speed. If I move the mouse or press a keys - it stops.

It's probably a hardware issue, but there might be a workaround or something that can be done to avoid this from happening.

```
uname -a
Linux 3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:16:32 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's a rather new **HP Pavilion 15** laptop with i7 CPU and 8GB RAM

```
~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

shows that there is a hybrid graphics controller inside

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2281
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
0a:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev ff)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a proprietary video driver. It can be done by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

After reboot you will be able to switch adapters. Now your Nvidia adapter consumes power but is not used.

Comment: Yes, there is an option to choose from System Tools -> "Configure NVIDIA X Server settings" and setting "Intel (power saving mode)" will hopefully resolve the issue, although "NVIDIA (performance mode)" makes the display better but as long I am not playing any games, the "Intel" mode is fine.